# Remote control a standalone application - TCP vs standard I/O

Tags: c++, process, stdout, stdin, tcp

I have a standalone application which I need to modify so that it can be remote controlled by other client programs.

So far the requirements are:

- The app can be started and closed by other programs, it does not need to be persistent
- We can start an instance of the app for each client program, nothing is shared.
- The client API for remote controlling should be as simple as possible
- The communication will be made of simple commands and possibly large images
- Client and controlled app will run on the same computer

Initially, I thought opening a TCP port on the app for remote controlling it. But the requirements make me think this could be done by simply starting the app in a process in the client, and communicating via standard input and output. Is this a good idea, and especially, does it handle large amounts of data?

Thanks for hints!

Comment: Are the other client programs located on the same computer or just on the same network? It sounds to me that TCP is for communication between computers, while stdin and stdout is for communication inside a computer. Please add this detail.

Comment: This question is rather broad and not really suitable for stackoverflow. You could also use named pipes, UDP or other methodes, depending on your particular requirements and constraints.

Comment: Why not just use `ssh` or similar "remote access" to the remote computer?

Comment: @RawBean TCP (or more general, sockets) is also suitable for communication between programs running on the same computer. An additional benefit over stdin/out is that the same code still works if you happen to move one of the programs to another computer.